# Cómo arreglar el error Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException en un porgrama Java que hace conexión con una BD en SQL

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, aplicación-escritorio

estoy tratando de hacer una aplicación de escritorio usando Java en [netbeans-8.2](/questions/tagged/netbeans-8.2), la cual se conecte a una BD en SQL Server Management Studio, lea datos, agregre datos y haga otro tipo de consultas. El programa en si me compila bien y se conecta bien a la BD en cuestión, pero a la hora de intentar introducir datos en la BD me sale el error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException.

Código de la conexión:

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author greter
 */
public class CConexion {
 Connection conectar;

String usuario = "usersql";
String pass = "fastafari*2022";
String bd = "dbprueba";
String ip = "localhost";
String puerto = "1433";

String cadena = "jdbc:sqlserver://"+ip+":"+puerto+"/"+bd;

public CConexion() {

}

public Connection establecerConexion(){
    try{
        
        String cadena = "jdbc:sqlserver://localhost:"+puerto+";"+"databaseName="+bd+";"+"encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true";
        conectar = DriverManager.getConnection(cadena,usuario,pass);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Se conectó correctamente a la BD");
        
    }catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error al conectar a la BD. error: "+ e.toString());
    } 
   return conectar; 
}
Statement createStatement(){
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("No soportado");
}
public void cerrar(){
    try{
        conectar.close();
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Se ha cerrado la conexion a la BD: "+ ex.toString());
    }
 }
}
```

y aquí está el código del botón

```
private void btnAgregarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
     
    LibrosDTO libro = new LibrosDTO();
    libro.setTitulo(tfTitulo.getText() );
    libro.setIsbn(tfISBN.getText());
    libro.setAutores(tfAutores.getText());
    libro.setEditorial(tfEditorial.getText());    
    
    
    //creacion de la conexion
    CConexion cone = new CConexion();
    //el que hace la manipulacion en la bd
   LibrosDAO libroDAO = new LibrosDAO(cone.conectar);
   int id = libroDAO.agregarLibro(libro); 
   if(id>0)
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserción de libro exitosa");
   else
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Inserción de libro fallida");
   //cierre de la conexion a la bd 
   cone.cerrar();
    
}
```

y por último el código de la clase DAO

```
public class LibrosDAO {
Connection conector;

public LibrosDAO(Connection conn){
    conector = conn;
}
//hacer insercion de un libro hacia la tabla de libros
public int agregarLibro(LibrosDTO libro){
    //objeto que almacena la instruccion sql
    PreparedStatement objetoSentSql = null;
    //para recibir los resultados
    ResultSet generatedKeys =null;
    int id = 0;
    
    String sql = "INSERT INTO libros"+"(titulo, isbn, autores,editorial)"+"VALUES(?,?,?,?)";
    
    try{
        //para que la base de datos no haga nada hasta que se le pida
        conector.setAutoCommit(false);
        objetoSentSql = conector.prepareStatement(sql,PreparedStatement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        objetoSentSql.setString(1,libro.getTitulo());
        objetoSentSql.setString(2,libro.getIsbn());
        objetoSentSql.setString(3,libro.getAutores());
        objetoSentSql.setString(4,libro.getEditorial());
        //hacer que la operacion de sql se realice
        objetoSentSql.executeUpdate();
        //recibimos el resultado de la operacion de insercion
        generatedKeys = objetoSentSql.getGeneratedKeys();
        if(generatedKeys.next()){
            id = generatedKeys.getInt(1);
        }
        conector.commit();
        
    }catch(SQLException ex){
        try{
            //deshace lo que se ejecuto si hay algun error
            conector.rollback();
        }catch(SQLException ex1){
            System.out.println("Error en recuperación de transacción");
        }
    }
    return id;
 }

}
```

si me pudieran ayudar por favor no se pq me da ese error

Comment: Lo puntos nulos son muy versátiles, pero en esencia, es que algo falta en la inserción. ¿Estás mandando algún field vacío?

Comment: Para que te ayuden a revisar de forma más efectiva, incluye una traza de error más completa. Las trazas de error en Java muestran toda la cadena de invocación de métodos y se puede ver la clase, método y línea donde falla. Así pues, procura siempre [edit] y añadir una traza más completa, no sólo la primera línea.

Comment: En estas lineas : ```CConexion cone = new CConexion();
    //el que hace la manipulacion en la bd
   LibrosDAO libroDAO = new LibrosDAO(cone.conectar);```. ***cone.conectar*** es nulo porque no se ha establecido la conexión.

Answer (score 0):

En estas lineas :

```
CConexion cone = new CConexion();     //el que hace la manipulacion en la bd   
LibrosDAO libroDAO = new LibrosDAO(cone.conectar);
```

***cone.conectar*** es nulo porque no has establecido la conexión. Debería ser algo como esto:

```
CConexion cone = new CConexion();     //el que hace la manipulacion en la bd   
 

cone.EstablecerConexion();

LibrosDAO libroDAO = new LibrosDAO(cone.conectar);
```

O directamente:

```
CConexion cone = new CConexion();     //el que hace la manipulacion en la bd  

LibrosDAO libroDAO = new LibrosDAO(cone.establecerConexion());
```